# H2 in memory import mv database programatically

Tags: database, spring-boot, h2

I have a `H2` `h2.mv.db` database physical file in `"users"` directory of my machine. I want my application using Spring Boot to use `H2` **in memory** database, but when the app start I want the in memory database to import the `h2.mv.db` file. I know I can export a `SQL` script then execute it manually using `H2` web application, but can this be achieved programatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the spring.datasource.url to point to the file.
Another approach to this problem is to export the SQL script as you said and put it inside a file called `src/main/resource/data.sql`.

> Spring Boot automatically picks up the data.sql file and run it against the H2 database during the application startup.

```
#persist the data  
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:/data/sampledata  
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:C:/data/sampledata
```

Source: https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-boot-h2-database

Comment: I was thinking about a use case in the app to import the file. It is possible to change and load the spring datasource url during execution of the program?